# How do I write an array of contents into a text file?

Tags: c++, arrays

The code is supposed to open an existing text file, transfer the contents into the array, then create a new text file and then write the array contents into the new text file. The problem I'm having is that the code only outputs the last line of the content from the new text file.

```
file.open("Patient.txt", ios::in);
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file >> arr[i].name >> arr[i].DOB >> arr[i].address >> arr[i].Dr_name >> arr[i].V_date;
        /*cout << arr[i].name << arr[i].DOB << arr[i].address << arr[i].Dr_name << arr[i].V_date << endl;*/
    }
    file.close();

    files.open("Patients_2.txt");

    if (files.is_open()) {
        for (i; i < 30; i++) {
            files << arr[i].name << arr[i].DOB << arr[i].address << arr[i].Dr_name << arr[i].V_date;
        }
    }
    files.close();

    patientss.open("Patients_2.txt");

    cout << "Patient 2: " << endl;
    while (!patientss.eof()) {
        getline(patientss, line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    patientss.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you read the first line of the file? When you read the last line of the file? When you read the last/2 line?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming, "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do"? Can you explain, step by step, what exactly does that `while` tell your computer to do? And then, exactly, what your `for` loop tells your computer to do?

Comment: i is initialize as 0, and the content is a total of 30 lines of strings.

Comment: `while (!patientss.eof()) {` avoid this pattern [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: The question isn't what the content is, or how many strings it is. The question is what exactly does your `while` loop and your `for` loop tell your computer to do?

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you read the first line of the file? When you read the last line of the file? When you read the last/2 line?

Comment: `i` never changes in the first loop so whatever data you read from the `Patient.txt`  it populates only one index of your array total. It's also unclear what value `i` has since that is not in the code presented.

Comment: Then if `i` was fixed to increment so the first file reading would work, what value would it have when we entered this loop; `for (i; i < 30; i++) {`

Comment: Unrelated: once you get the rest working, `file >> arr[i].name >> arr[i].DOB >> arr[i].address >> arr[i].Dr_name >> arr[i].V_date;` will read words from a file, so you get garbage like the patient's last name being read into `DOB`. You'll need more smarts here. Similarly `files << arr[i].name << arr[i].DOB << arr[i].address << arr[i].Dr_name << arr[i].V_date;` will output one long blob of text with no way for a program to tell one field from another. You will want to output a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

This loop has a few problems:

```
 while (!file.eof()) {
        file >> arr[i].name >> arr[i].DOB ....
```

- You never increase `i` so the same `arr[i]` will be overwritten time and time again.
- You use `!file.eof()` as a condition to stop reading. `eof()` does not get set until *after* you've tried to read beyond the end of the file, which means that *if* you had increased `i` as you should, the last `arr` would be empty / broken. Instead check if the extraction from the stream succeeded. Since the *stream* is returned when you do `stream >> var` and has an overload for `explicit operator bool() const` which returns `!fail()` you can do this check directly in your loop:
       `while(stream >> var) { extraction success }`

Using formatted input (`>>`) for string fields that are likely to contain spaces is however not a good idea. Your name, `nung khual`, would be split so `nung` would go into `name` and `khual` would go into `DOB`. It's better to use a field separator that is very unlikely to be included in anyone's name. `\n` is usually good and works well with `std::getline`.

`std::getline` returns the *stream* that you gave as an argument which means that you can chain `getline`s similarly to `stream >> var1 >> var2`, except it's a little more verbose.
`getline(getline(stream, var1), var2)` will put the first line in `var1` and the second line in `var2`.

To make input and output a little simpler you can add stream operators for your data type and make the input stream operator use `getline` for your fields.

Example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct data_t {
    std::string name;
    std::string DOB;
    std::string address;
    std::string Dr_name;
    std::string V_date;
};

// input stream operator using chained getlines
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, data_t& d) {
    using std::getline;
    return getline(getline(getline(getline(getline(is,
           d.name), d.DOB), d.address), d.Dr_name), d.V_date);
}

// output stream operator
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const data_t& d) {
    return os << d.name << '\n'
              << d.DOB << '\n'
              << d.address << '\n'
              << d.Dr_name << '\n'
              << d.V_date << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<data_t> arr;

    if(std::ifstream file("Patient.txt"); file) {
        data_t tmp;
        while(file >> tmp) {                           // remember, no eof() needed
            arr.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    if(std::ofstream file("Patients_2.txt"); file) {
        for(const data_t& d : arr) {
            file << d;
        }
    }

    if(std::ifstream patientss("Patients_2.txt"); patientss) {
        data_t tmp;
        while(patientss >> tmp) {
            std::cout << tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should overload the formatted insertion and extraction operators in your patient class:

```
struct Patient
{
    std::string name;
    std::string dob;
    std::string address;
    std::string dr_name;
    std::string v_date;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Patient& p);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Patient& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Patient& p)
{
    std::getline(input, p.name);
    std::getline(input, p.dob);
    std::getline(input, p.address);
    std::getline(input, p.dr_name);
    std::getline(input, p.v_date);
    return input;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Patient& p)
{
    output << p.name << "\n";
    output << p.dob << "\n";
    output << p.address << "\n";
    output << p.dr_name << "\n";
    output << p.v_date << "\n";
    return output;
}
```

The above makes input and output easier:

```
std::vector<Patient> database;
Patient p;
while (input_file >> p)
{
    database.push_back(p);
}

const unsigned int quantity = database.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++quantity)
{
    output_file << database[i];
}
```

The above code also supports the concepts of *encapsulation* and *data hiding*.  The `Patient struct` is in charge or reading its members because it knows the data types of the members.  The code external to the `Patient` is only concerned with the input and output of a `Patient` instance (doesn't care about the internals).